# Comma separate in overloading ostream and istream in struct

Tags: c++

I want my struct PersonData to get the output (firstname,lastname,personage,countrycode,income) with the comma seperator.

I have written this code but it only works with whitespace. 
   So output will be (firstname lastname personage countrycode income)

How can i change this to ,(comma) instead?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const PersonData &pd)
{
output << pd.firstName << " " << pd.lastName << " " << pd.age << " " << pd.countryCode << 
" " << pd.income;
return output;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& indata, PersonData &pd) 
{
indata >> pd.firstName >> pd.lastName >> pd.age >> pd.countryCode >> pd.income;
}
```

Comment: `output << ","` instead of `output << " "`?

Comment: i am reading the from a text file with values like: Peter,Petersson,27,SE,28.4
Daniel,Danielsson,28,SE,30.7
Karl,Karlsson,19,NO,10.       i read these values into a vector<Persondata> but when i try to write from the vector again to a new file i get errors.

Comment: If you know how to output, but have issue with input, show working output and clearly state something like: "how to read comma separated values".

Comment: ok thanks i will look it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change symbols (string literals) you've been outputting between `PersonData`'s fields.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const PersonData &pd)
{
output << pd.firstName << ", " << pd.lastName << ", " << pd.age << ", " << pd.countryCode << 
", " << pd.income;
return output;
}
```